# Disable unnecessary unsafe warning when cfg given

Tags: rust

I have two versions of a structure, one is enabled when a feature is enabled, the other when its not enabled, as shown below. The thing is that one contains *unsafe* methods, the other does not. So when these functions are called in other parts of the library, I have surrounded them with an `unsafe { }` block. When my library is compiled without the feature enabled, I get the following warning:

> unnecessary `unsafe` block

How do I get around / disable this warning when its not applicable, ie. when the feature is not enabled.

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
pub struct MyStruct {
    // some fields
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
pub struct MyStruct {
    // some different fields
}

#[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
impl MyStruct {
    pub unsafe fn my_func() {}
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn my_func() {}
}

fn main() {
    // I want to get rid of this unsafe when its not needed.
    unsafe { MyStruct::my_func() };
}
```

Comment: well the same cfg https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5084b667e5d8ed1fe8f20b1be6df95ee

Comment: your question can be answer but seem you have a xy problem. Having a either unsafe or not function based on a feature is weird at best, I would say it's dangerous.

Comment: @Stargateur If you want to annotate the callers, `#[allow(unused_unsafe)]` is better than a cfg IMHO.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman but ignore the warming is fundamentally different, this warning exist for a reason.

Comment: `#[cfg_attr(not(feature = "my-feature"), allow(unused_unsafe))]` if you're paranoid. Or just make both unsafe; I believe the latter makes more sense.

Comment: @SOFe Making both unsafe is the easy solution, but if this is library and you're exporting them this is not a good idea.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yep it is a library and they are being exported.

Comment: @Stargateur @ Chayim Friedman aren't attributes over expressions unstable?

Comment: You can use it for the statement.

Comment: I agree with @Stargateur that having the same API suddently becoming `unsafe` on a feature activation feels weird. It feels like you are missing a safe boundary wrapper, which is safe no matter the feature used.

Comment: @jthulhu actually this is a good idea, except That means I now have to write a wrapper for like 10 functions... which is ugly...

Comment: @t348575 this is a common practice in Rust. You should not expose an `unsafe` interface if you could write a safe interface yourself without any (runtime) overhead. Image if the people who wrote the standard library didn't write a safe interface to their collections and just exposed implementation details how painful that would be (and if you don't believe that would be painful, convince yourself it would be).

Comment: cargo features are additive. If this is a library, there can be two packages depending on your library, one requesting the feature and one not. The one not requesting the feature compiles fine until used together with the one that requests the feature, in which it will suddenly stop compiling with an error of calling unsafe function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these cases are only inside your library, so you can afford little incovenience, you can use a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! call {
    // For static methods.
    {
        unsafe {
            $($method:ident)::+ ( $($arg:expr),* $(,)? )
        }
    } => {{
        #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
        let v = unsafe { $($method)::+ ( $($arg),* ) };
        #[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
        let v = $($method)::+ ( $($arg),* );
        v
    }};
    // For instance methods.
    {
        unsafe {
            $object:ident . $method:ident ( $($arg:expr),* $(,)? )
        }
    } => {{
        #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
        let v = unsafe { $object . $method ( $($arg),* ) };
        #[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
        let v = $object . $method ( $($arg),* );
        v
    }};
}

call!(unsafe { MyStruct::my_func() });
call!(unsafe { v.my_method() });
```

This macro does not allow generics or complex expression as the receiver. Extending it to support generics should be fairly easy; supporting complex expressions will probably require a proc macro.

There is a better way to write the macro: instead of requiring `unsafe` inside it, and wrapping the call in `cfg`, just do something unsafe inside it, thus always requiring `unsafe` outside of it. This also solves the problem with generics and complex receivers:

```rust
pub(crate) unsafe fn always_unsafe() {}

macro_rules! call {
    ($($call:tt)+) => {{
        $crate::always_unsafe();
        $($call)*
    }};
}

unsafe {
    call!(MyStruct::my_func());
}
unsafe {
    call!(v.my_method());
}
```

Comment: With this solution, I think it's even more readable if you remove the `unsafe` altogether.

Comment: @jthulhu If the operation is unsafe, I think it should be clear in the source code, so you can e.g. grep for `unsafe`, or just verify it is safe.

Comment: Maybe calling the macro `maybe_unsafe` instead, and calling it with braces to make it visually (and text-greppingly) look like an `unsafe` block?

Comment: @jthulhu You can do that, but I don't like the idea.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman dont know if this matters but my feature purely exists to differentiate between whether my library is being compiled and linked with a C / C++ application or used in a rust app. (That way I can return FFI safe types (*const char in this particular case), or stick to a Vec if in a rust app

Comment: @t348575 Then? Why does it matter to this answer?

Comment: @jthulhu Posted an edit about another version of the macro that also solves you concern.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that seems better indeed. +1